# The mosts common topics that developer technical tests ask

Tags: game-industry, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are typical job interview questions related to game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/what-are-typical-job-interview-questions-related-to-game-development)

I have a technical test on the horizon, and I'm brushing up on my 3D maths and algorithmic stuff - there are websites that have lists and lists of technical questions such as 'How would you check to see if a string was a palindrome?' and also perhaps, 'How would you check to see if there was a palindrome anywhere in this string?'

Also things like calculating complex recursion on paper and Big O notation. What are the other key things to practise for these kinds of test?

Comment: Good luck! And and please keep us up to date

Comment: @Tili Got it! Woohoo!

Comment: Nice! Now, what did they ask ? :p

Comment: @Tili not as advanced as I expected, things like how to delete all the elements in a binary tree, how to count the bits in a byte, how to reverse a linked list. A few things on design patterns. Nothing on asymptotic notation, huzzah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practice sleeping well, being on time, taking a bath, dressing well and not least smalltalking well. It's a job, so getting people to like you is way more important than a few points on the technical test.

For the technical part I obviously can't tell you what will be in a test I don't know anything about, but if I were to make such a test I'd probably make it slightly more practical than your list suggests, with stuff like writing a brute force solver for a combinatorics problem or finding bugs or security issues in a given piece of code.

Also be sure that you are well acquainted with reference passing and reference manipulation. That field can make some quick but tricky questions.

Do you know how long the test will be? Unless it's hours you'll probably not be given any real programming task.

Comment: It's going to be about half an hour and then the test's going to be discussed - short I know, but it's a really cool little start-up studio with funding for a high profile AAA title and I REALLY want the job, so... prepare prepare prepare!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [The Guerrilla Guide to Interviewing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000073.html). It might give you an idea of what "people" want when hiring a good programmer.